# Redhat Openshift workloads impact during network outage

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

We have requirement to setup on prem kubernetes that can continue to serve applications even when there is disconnection from internet.

We are considering Redhat openshift. My question is does redhat openshift continue to service existing workloads during network outage?

I understand that during outage new images may not be pulled or deployed but I want to know if existing apps are impacted anyway.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all Kubernetes distributions, applications running on the cluster will continue to run even without an internet connection (obviously as long as the application itself does not rely on internet access).

As you correctly note, new applications can typically not be started without access to the registry where the image is stored. So if an application crashes, it might not be able to restart.

In your case for OpenShift, I would recommend to look at a [disconnected installation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/installing/installing-mirroring-installation-images.html) in connection with a local registry.

With a local registry mirror you can function completely without any internet access whatsoever. Image registries like Artifactory or Nexus allow you to cache images locally - this is typically called a mirrored registry or a pull-through registry.